# Fastest way to insert values to android sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I want to create a database, and fill it at the start of application. It will remain same and will never change. There will be like 1000 entries. What is the good way to do this?

I created the table so far, but now i have to fill it with 1000 entries. Is there an UI for it?

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+
            UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            USER_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
            USER_TYPE+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
            USER_CLASS+" TEXT NOT NULL);"


        );
```

Comment: Where do these 1000 entries come from? If you know them before shipping the app, take some tool to build the database (there are [GUI tools for sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools)) and load it via [SQLiteAssetOpenHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways to improve the performance:

As Tsunaze suggests, you should do this in another thread, you can check AsyncTask which is the "default" tool provided in the SDK to do this.

---

Consider using transactions:

```
db.beginTransaction();
for(...){
    db.insert(...);
}
db.commit();
```

In this way you will only write to the database when you finish inserting all the values, speeding up the process.

---

Do massive inserts:

```
insert into table
select value1X, value1Y, value1Z
union all
select value2X, value2Y, value2Z
union all
select value3X, value3Y, value3Z
union all
select value4X, value4Y, value4Z
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create file "table_inserts.sql" and put it in "raw" folder.

```
    private void insertValues(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.table_inserts))));
            String s;
            while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                db.execSQL(s);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

or your can write all inserts in code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in a thread, to no block the main UI:

```
public void addObjects(List<Object> objects, OnQueryListener listener){
listener.begin();
database.beginTransaction();
for(int i = 0; i < objects.size();i++{
// Add
}
database.setTransactionSuccessful();
database.endTransaction();
listener.end();
}

private interface OnQueryListener{
void begin();
void end();
}
```

And in your main Code do something like this :

```
Handler h = new Handler();
Thread t = new Thread(run);
t.start();

Runnable run = new Runnable{

void run(){
addObjects(objects, new OnQueryListener{

void begin(){

}
void end(){
handler.post(new Runnable{
void run(){
// On your main UI
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

It's not something i've tested on real code, just something at the top of my head.